# My Javascript won't work in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I created a script for a basic HTML/CSS page I programmed a while ago, it works fine in a standard website but when I try and import it into my client's new Wordpress Website the script doesn't work.

New Website: http://www.fencingfabrication.com.au/quote-calculator/

HTML

```
*<h1>S & N Fencing</h1>
        <h2>Get a fencing quote today</h2>
        <h4>Requires browser Javascript</h4>
        <h3>Gate dimenstions</h3>
        Wood Look 10% extra<input type="checkbox"  id="check1" value=false><br>
        <p>Length in mm</p><input id="a" type="text"/>
        <p>Width in mm</p><input id="b" type="text"/>
        <br><br><br>

        <input type="button" onclick="val()" value="Calculate Total"/>*


<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var a,b;    /*creates variables a and b*/

    var gatePrice = 500; /*price per square meter of fencing*/

    function setValues() /*assigns value of a and b using id*/
    {
        a = Number(document.getElementById("a").value); 
        b = Number(document.getElementById("b").value);

    }

    function check_tenpercent(checkbox) /*checks if check boxes are checked and adds assigns values to variable*/
    {
        var retval = 1;
        if(checkbox.checked == true)
        {
            retval = 1.1;
        }
        return retval;
    }

    function val()
    {
        setValues();
        var rate1 = check_tenpercent(document.getElementById("check1"));


        gateMeters = a*b / 1000000;

        gateMeters = gateMeters * rate1;

        gateMeters = gateMeters * gatePrice;


        result = gateMeters;
        if(result >= 700){
        alert("The total fencing price for this job is" + " $" + result.toFixed(2)); /*gives out total price of fencing*/
        }else {
            alert("This job would cost" + " $" + result.toFixed(2) + ". " + "Minimum price is $700");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your CSS and JavaScript files by enqueueing them in your functions.php

> When you’re creating your theme, you may want to create additional stylesheets or JavaScript files. However, remember that a WordPress
>   website will not just have your theme active, it will also be using
>   many different plugins. So that everything works harmoniously, it’s
>   important that theme and plugins load scripts and stylesheets using
>   the standard WordPress method. This will ensure the site remains
>   efficient and that there are no incompatibility issues.
>
> Adding scripts and styles to WordPress is a fairly simple process.
>   Essentially, you will create a function that will enqueue all of your
>   scripts and styles. When enqueuing a script or stylesheet, WordPress
>   creates a handle and path to find your file and any dependencies it
>   may have (like jQuery) and then you will use a hook that will insert
>   your scripts and stylesheets.

[Some instructions from the WordPress theme handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the content is escaped by **WordPress** `kses` filter.
`Kses` filter makes input HTML safe.
`Kses` filter is enabled by default if you don't have the capability of `unfiltered_html` (by default, Editor and Administrator have this permission if the site is not multisite. In multisite, only Super Administrator has that permission).

`WordPress` escapes input HTML in output. You could stop escaping HTML by removing filters, but it makes WordPress unsafe a bit.

You should check the content in the edit screen, and then, you should check the output content.

Answer (score 0):

Your function **val()** is not being called, when we click on **Calculate** button. If you inspect that button then you will see there is no **onclick** defined.